# Behaviour of dispatch function on catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I was building a login system on my app and I found a weird behaviour of the dispatch function.

I'm using React with Redux, Redux-Thunk and Redux-Form. 
On my actions/index.js file, after making an axios request, the dispatch function, when I'm using the .then().catch() syntax works perfectly but when I change to async/await syntax the second dispatch doesn't work any more. I try to find explanation online but I didn't found any that clarified my problem. Does someone know why does that happens?

Version that works perfectly:

```
export const submitLoginForm = values => dispatch => {
axios.post(
        '/auth/local/login',
        qs.stringify({
            email: values.email,
            password: values.password
        })
    )
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch(
            stopSubmit('enterpriseLogin', {
                _error: 'Error description...'
            })
        );
    });
}
```

Version that second dispatch doesn't work:

```
export const submitLoginForm = values => async dispatch => {
try {
    const res = await axios.post(
        '/auth/local/login',
        qs.stringify({
            email: values.email,
            password: values.password
        })
    );
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
} catch (err) {
    //Doesnt Work !!
    dispatch(
        stopSubmit('enterpriseLogin', {
            _error: 'Error description...'
        })
    );
}
}
```